# Can not find module Electron

Tags: angular, electron

I am working on one angular app with electron js.  In Package.json 
I updated

```
main: "./dist/index.js"
```

which is entry point for electron. Now, when starting application, it start prompting with error

```
Not able to find module electron like dist/node_modules/electron.
```

I know some silly mistake but not able to resolve this. Any help ?

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue? App is running fine but when i package it, i am getting this error

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check electron forlder in your node_modules folder of the App.
If there is not an electron module then you need to install it by this command-

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

Comment: hey !! that is already available, it is full fledged running app. I just tried updating main script.

Comment: It might be path issue that you are providing like  "./dist/index.js" .

Comment: This file exist there. As simple as that, it is not loading electron module while executing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your index.html  base href. Add a `.` before slash.

```
<base href="./">
```

change "main" value to main.js

```
"main": "main.js",
```

and also add two lines in the packege.json under script

```
"electron": "ng build && electron .",
"electron-aot": "ng build --prod && electron ."
```

and you can try to run it by the following command

```
npm run electron
```

And it works for me

Comment: I dont agree with this one. Even if i tried, did not work too. Electron module not getting loaded while loading index.js (entry point for electron) file, i hope it does not have anything to do with index.html.